# JSON not beeing accepted by JS

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to do a simple JS script that will take JSON data from this URL http://media.overkillsoftware.com/stats/missions.json and put them inside two variables, one named *daily* and the other *weekly*.

I tried a few scripts, but none of them but worked and xhr.status was always 4 (not 2 or 3, just 4).

I am a complete beginner and barely understand this, could someone point me at right direction? I only need them to be parsed to two variables.

Comment: You will not be able to load this resource with AJAX, as there is no CORS.

Comment: But the site doesn't support JSONP, so what are my other options?

Comment: Server-side proxy for example.

Comment: As @dfsq said, get your server to fetch that data, then you can get the browser to request it from your server (which can massage it or do whatever you wish).

Comment: I'm afraid server-side proxy won't be possible since I don't have access to one. Any other ideas?